# What is the type of a row in a Csv type provider?

Tags: types, f#, type-providers

I created a Csv type provider:

```
type AssetInfo = CsvProvider<Sample="AssetInfoFS.csv", // must be a Literal
                             HasHeaders=true,
                             ResolutionFolder=projDataPath,
                             AssumeMissingValues=false,
                             CacheRows=false>
```

Then I loaded some info and discarded some rows:

```
let assetInfo = AssetInfo.Load(projDataPath + @"AssetInfoFS.csv")
let traderInfoRecords =
    assetInfo.Rows
    |> Seq.filter (fun elem -> Set.contains elem.Ticker tradedTickerSet)
```

Next I tried to create a record type that would have a row as one of its values:

```
type Asset = {Ticker: string; Info: CsvProvider<...>.Row; DataFrame: Frame<DateTime,string>}
```

I got `CsvProvider<...>.Row` by using `MoveNext()` and then `Current` and `GetType()` on an `IEnumerator` for `assetInfo.Rows`. Unfortunately the compiler does not accept that expression as a type. I tried other things with no success.

How can I find the type of a row of `assetInfo` so that I can use it in the Asset type declaration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, the row will have the type `AssetInfo.Row`.

I made a brief example where I have a CSV with two columns, named Header1 and Header2. I can now do the following:

```
module Test

open FSharp.Data

type File = CsvProvider<"""..\test.csv""">

let f (input : File.Row) = input.Header1
```

Where by explicitly naming the type of the argument to `f`, Intellisense shows me both of the fields on the type.